# bootstrap-select not selecting the correct item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap select  Bootstrap-select v1.7.2 in Angular. When I select some option from drop down it selects some other option.

Plunker is setup here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MRYOkW?p=preview

(code is in dashboard.html and dashboard.js)

That's how I am creating it. bootstrap-dropdown is the directive that initiates the drop-down.

```
<select ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Logic" name="ddlLogic"   bootstrap-dropdown >
    <option>Contains</option>
    <option>Greater Than</option>
    <option>Less Than</option>
    <option>Equal To</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to add value attribute on your options that would set value of `ng-model` on select of any option

```
<select ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Logic" name="ddlLogic" bootstrap-dropdown>
    <option value="">Contains</option>
    <option value="Greater">Greater Than</option>
    <option value="Less">Less Than</option>
    <option value="Equal">Equal To</option>
</select>
```

**Update**

If you want to render select option dynamically I'd refer you to use [**`ng-options`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) which support select perfectly. You can select object on selection of option

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DpDteZdH2rKRKcUIJnfq?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

problem is you can't add option value property . either set value property or generate this using ng-repeat option

Comment: thats also makes sense

Comment: i tried what you said here http://plnkr.co/edit/OiGqSR4Nx68METzG3Gaw?p=preview  will be kind enough to take a look

Answer (score 0):

Above answer must be the right answer but, It seems like you had an unwanted empty option an it was messing the index. By adding a real one it started to work.

```
<select ng-model="vm.CurrCustomer.Logic" name="ddlLogic"   bootstrap-dropdown >
        <option></option>
        <option>Contains</option>
        <option>Greater Than</option>
        <option>Less Than</option>
        <option>Equal To</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: I was just pointing out that it could work without the value parameter by adding the empty option.

Comment: then how the `ng-model` will know what value to be store?